# I need to access /library on iOS 5.1.1 from a PC without jailbreaking

Tags: ios

I know that this might be useless, but I just wanted to ask.

I have an iPhone 4s running iOS 5.1.1, a few months ago my wife did set a restrictions passcode on it to prevent our daughter from changing some settings accidentally while she's playing games with the phone.

Now my wife forgot that code and needs to change some settings herself and of course she's not able to do so.

I've got a way around this but it's necessary to access /library/keychains to do it.

Since the phone is not jailbroken, I can't access that path (Using i-Funbox)

Is there any other way that I can use it to access this path ?

Is there any way around to reset this passcode ?

Answer (score 0):

Without jailbreak, you can't. However, you can easily jailbreak the phone using Absinthe 2.0.4.

if you don't want to do that at all, you can make a backup of the device using iTunes, then restore its firmware to factory defaults, then the pass code will be gone. You'll get back all your data after re-syncing with iTunes.

Comment: Thanks H2CO3 for the reply, I have some questions here: Using absinthe to jailbreak the phone, will it erase the data or keep all the data there ? The other question, if I opt for the backup thing, do you mean to reinstall the iOS ? If so, this way all data will be gone then after the iOS installation I should restore from the backup, won't this lead to restoring the passcode again ?

Comment: @user1543206 absinthe won't delete anything from your phone. Also, as far as I know, the pass code is not backed up.